# Call external API by Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm calling my API on PHP server by Angular JS:

```
 $http({method: 'POST', url: 'my api...',
```

And my call is always canceled and generated the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://kni.prz.edu.pl/querye/api/querye. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

**How to enable Cross Requests in Angular JS?**

The canceled is not from server.

Comment: Try to fire up a local server and see if your request goes trough.

Comment: Local server is not a solution, still the same error. Davin what are you mean?

Comment: @DavinTryon: isn't it obvious from the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the issue is in fact on the server side. You need to add a response header to allow cross domain requests:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Be aware that adding this will allow any domain to send requests to your host.

If you don't have control of the server, you'll need to try JSONP, see: [$http.jsonp](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#jsonp)

Comment: putting 'localhost' is safer than putting *.

Answer (score 1):

To enable cross site requests

[angularjs $http docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Most probably you won't get this error when running a deployed instance as you won't be on the localhost.

For testing purposes, you can do:

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```